# Handle null exception get property method

Tags: java

I have a config file which I'm reading via java.util.Properties class. When property is not present in a file getProperty() method returns null. I would like to throw an exception if any property is not present in config file. So how should I do it? Need best way to do it.

Comment: `if (getProperty() == null) { throw new Exception(); }`

Comment: It will work but everywhere I need to put the null check. Which is not acceptable. Need best way to do it.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Then you need to specify that in your question. Right now you only said "I would like to throw an exception if any property is not present". You need to define what you consider "best"

Comment: I tried creating a method . In that method I am passing properties object and key name, if key is not present in the method then I am throwing null exception there itself. And I am using this method everywhere in the project.

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap a `Properties` instance in a custom class that adds this additional logic :

```
public class MandatoryProperties{

   private Properties properties;

   public MandatoryProperties(Properties properties){
       this.properties = properties;
   }

   public String getProperty(String key){
      String value = properties.getProperty(key);
      if (value == null){
          throw new RuntimeException(...);
      }
      return value;
   }
}
```

And use it as :

```
MandatoryProperties properties = new MandatoryProperties(properties);
String value = properties.getProperty("aKey");
```

Here the example throws an unchecked exception. Use a checked exception if your use case fits better with.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the keyword `throw`.

You can throw a checked exception, which must be caught or throws, or a runtime exception, which doesn't have to be caught.

The syntax is the following :

```
if (null == getProperty("Propertyname")) {
    throw new RuntimeException("myMessage");
}
```

You can also create your own Exception, with creating a class extending Exception.

Answer (score 0):

I will base my answer [on davidxxx's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51993715/1153988) but I'd be lazier by inheriting my class from `Properties`.

```
public class MandatoryProperties extends java.util.Properties {
    @Override
    public String getProperty(String key) {
        String value = super.getProperty(key);
        if (value == null){
           throw new RuntimeException("Unknown property " + key);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

This requires a bit less code and allows you to declare it as a `Properties`.

Note that could be interesting to 'wrap' a `Properties` instance in some cases.